# Excel: Proportional monthly distribution of sample values over a time period spanning different months

Tags: excel, sample, period, distribute

I am trying to get my head around an MS excel formula for a scenario I have.

I am recording discharges over various sample periods.  These sample periods will last anywhere from 24 hrs to 1 week.  The sample period will be recorded with a start and end time (dd/mm/yy hh:mm).

I want to be able to report the sum discharge total for all sample periods for each calendar month, but ensuring that any sample periods that span two months (i.e. 27/02/24 14:00 >> 05/03/24 14:00) have the total discharge value proportionately distributed between each month total.  I acknowledge that this assumes that the discharges are constant rate, which they are for this task.  For the time range in brackets, this would be ~34% of the sample period total allocated to Feb-24 as an example.

If anyone can suggest a formula for F3 to satisfy what I've described above, that would be fantastic.

Screenshot attached.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgHPX.png)

I haven't tried anything so far, because I don't really know where to start with this.  I've tried in vain to find a solution online.

Comment: Your screenshot requires a microscope to be read... Please provide data as a formatted table instead.

Comment: I've updated the screenshot image.  I'm afraid I don't know how to provide data as a formatted table - I don't know what that even means.

Comment: @ETP. You can use this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the overlap formula

```
Min(startTime1,startTime2)-max(endTime1,endTime2)
```

to give you the number of days and hours which fall within the current month. When applied as an array formula in this case it would give you

```
=LET(dis,C$2:C$4,
startDis,A$2:A$4,
endDis,B$2:B$4,
startMonth,E2,
endMonth,EOMONTH(E2,0)+1,
overlap,IF(endMonth<endDis,endMonth,endDis)-IF(startMonth>startDis,startMonth,startDis),
posOverlap,IF(overlap<0,0,overlap),
SUM(posOverlap*dis/(endDis-startDis)))
```

[image]

Note the use of eomonth(E2,0)+1 which takes you to midnight on the last day of the current month.

Comment: Tom, thanks so much for sharing this solution.  This is a lovely tidy way of doing exactly what I'd asked.

Comment: As I suppose is often the way with examples shared on here, I created a simplified example, without sensitive info.  When now implementing your solution to my actual workbook, I've discovered that the fantastic array formula you provided doesn't work with rows beneath for Discharge Start, Discharge End and Discharge  that presently show #N/A values due to being drawn in using a VLOOKUP.  Is there a way to subtly amend the array formula to ignore rows that are computing #N/A values and therefore causing the sum monthly total to equate to a #N/A also.  Many thanks for your input so far. ETP

Comment: It should be enough to change the last line of the formula to SUM(IFERROR(posOverlap*dis/(endDis-startDis),0)))